# Angular 2 - Full Calendar not working

Tags: angular, heroku, fullcalendar

Hello I have an Angular 2 Project using fullcalendar. I have a problem when I'm trying to deploy it to heroku and I get a build error like this.

```
remote:        ERROR in node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(695,36): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
remote:        node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(696,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
remote:        node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(697,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
remote:        node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(759,22): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
remote:        node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(775,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
remote:        node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(988,23): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryEventObject'.
remote:        node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(1401,70): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryAjaxSettings'.
remote:        node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(1603,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
remote:        node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(1623,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
remote:        node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(2588,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
remote:        node_modules/ng-fullcalendar/src/calendar.component.d.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module ''fullcalendar'' has no exported member 'Options'.
remote:        src/app/components/view-calendar/view-calendar.component.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module ''fullcalendar'' has no exported member 'Options'.
```

I stumbled upon on how to [resolve the issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3991) by installing the following

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery@3.2.7
```

But I still get the error when pushing and deploying the code to heroku.

**EDIT**

Here are the dependencies under my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   "@angular/animations": "^5.2.3",
   "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
   "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/material": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
   "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
   "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
   "@types/jquery": "^3.2.7",
   "angular-calendar": "^0.23.6",
   "angular-material": "^1.1.6",
   "axios": "^0.17.1",
   "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
   "core-js": "^2.4.1",
   "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
   "fullcalendar": "^3.6.1",
   "jquery": "^3.3.1",
   "jsonwebtoken": "^8.1.1",
   "moment": "^2.20.1",
   "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.13",
   "ng-fullcalendar": "^1.4.6",
   "ng-modal": "^1.0.2",
   "ng-sidebar": "^6.0.5",
   "ng2-opd-popup": "^1.1.21",
   "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
   "popper.js": "^1.12.9",
   "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
   "underscore": "^1.8.3",
   "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
},
```

Comment: Are you deploying the dev version to Heroku or the production version? --save-dev only adds dependencies to the development version.

Comment: I transfered it to the dependencies. I still get the error in heroku

Comment: Are you still referencing another version of jQuery at the same time? What do your imports look like?

Answer (score 0):

Either use `npm install --save @types/jquery@3.2.7` (instead of `--save-dev`) before deploying to Heroku, or deploy your "dev" version to Heroku.

Comment: `"fullcalendar": "^3.6.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.7",`

Here are my dependencies